# How to save an image displayed in the stock browser without downloading it a second time?

Tags: downloading, images, stock-browser, download-manager

I am trying to save a scanned image from a printer on the local network with the stock Android browser. The browser interface looks something like this:

[image]

As soon as I click "start scan", the printer begins scanning the image. When complete, it is displayed in the little box on the right and a message pops up near the bottom instructing me to right-click the image to save it.

Now, in the stock Android browser, long-pressing on the image displays a menu which provides an option for saving the image. Unfortunately, the download always fails - and I think I know why. The printer does not keep a copy of the scanned image and immediately deletes it after the browser finishes loading it. This is a problem because the Android download manager will attempt to download the image *a second time*.

How can I save a copy of the image that is already displayed in the browser? Chrome and Firefox for Android both use the built-in download manager, so using them made no difference.

Comment: Have you tried [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser&hl=en)

Comment: @t0mm13b: I just gave it a try - sadly I get the same results. The download fails.